Charging with Stripe using my own subscription model
I am building a tool which has it's own variable subscription model. The charges could be weekly, monthly, yearly or something in between depending on the services they choose. I am looking for a payment provider in which I can create a subscription which does not automatically charge the users, but only saves the user information so I can charge the customer when I want to using my own cron jobs. The price is also going to be variable.
Is this possible with Stripe? If so, how can I approach this problem the best way?
I've already looked through API docs, but only found Stripe's own subscription system. Even though it's very customizable, it doesn't meet my requirements as far as I could read through the docs.

With Stripe, you can collect payment method details from your customer and save them for future payments. This is covered in details in their guide here. They show the parameter setup_future_usage: 'off_session' to indicate that you plan to reuse those details for future payments controlled/initiated by you.
